# How to loop through two list and append key,val pair?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm trying two loop through a text file and create a dict which holds `dict[line_index]=word_index_position` which means the key is the line number and the value is all the words in that line. The goal is to create a "matrix" so that a the user later on should be able to specify x,y coordinates (line, word_index_position) and retrieve a word in those coordinates, if there is any (Not sure how it is going to work with a dict, since it's not ordered). Below is the loop to create the dict.

```
try:
    f = open("file.txt", "r")
except Exception as e:
    print("Skriv in ett korrekt filnamn")
uppslag = dict()
num_lines = 0

for line in f.readlines():
    num_lines += 1
    print(line)
    for word in line.split():
        print(num_lines)
        print(word)
        uppslag[num_lines] = word
f.close()
uppslag
```

Loop works as it's supposed to, but `uppslag[num_lines] = word` seems to only store the last word in each line. Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Comment: Why are you even using a `dict` when you already know that the line numbers are in a continuous sequence? Just use a 2d list instead.

Comment: You should really use a context manager to handle that file object. You can iterate over the file object directly, no need to use `.readlines()`.

Comment: @AjayDabas is right, especially since you write _The goal is to create a "matrix" so that a the user later on should be able to specify x,y coordinates (line, word_index_position) and retrieve a word in those coordinates, if there is any_

Comment: @AMC The reason is because the particular exercise specifies the use of a dict, I'm very grateful for AjayDabas suggestion and I agree that it's a better solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of overwriting the `word`:

```
for word in line.split():
    print(num_lines)
    print(word)
    uppslag[num_lines] = word
```

you may be better off saving the whole line:

```
uppslag[num_lines] = line.split()
```

This way you'll be able to find the 3rd word in 4th line as:

```
uppslag[4][3]
```

Comment: That is really neat, thank you for taking your time to provide this solution and showing how a dict can be indexed. Highly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

`uppslag[num_lines] = word` is overwriting the dictionary entry for key `num_lines` every time it is called. You can use a list to hold all the words:

```
for line in f:
    num_lines += 1
    print(line)

    uppslag[num_lines] = []  # initialize dictionary entry with empty list

    for word in line.split():
        print(num_lines, word)

        uppslag[num_lines].append(word) # add new word to list
```

You can write the same code in a more compact form, since `line.split()` already returns a list:

```
for line_number, line in enumerate(f):
    uppslag[line_number] = line.split()
```

If there is a word on every line (i.e. the line index will be continuous) you can use a list instead of a dictionary, and reduce your code to a one-line list comprehension:

```
uppslag = [line.split() for line in f]
```

Comment: That is almost to compact for this exercise, must say I'm really impressed. Thank you for taking your time to show how it can be done!

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a dictionary, or `.readlines()`.

```py
with open("file.txt") as words_file:
    words = [line.split() for line in words_file]
```